# Is "I'm paraphrasing myself when I say this..." autological?

Tags: semantics

A friend of mine posted the following on his Facebook wall:

I'm paraphrasing myself when I say this...

I know this isn't a paradox, is it autological? Is it recursive? Is it even a true statement? If he had said "I'm expressing myself when I say this...", it's at least self-descriptive, but I'm not sure when it comes to "paraphrasing" because that seems to imply a shortening of the original statement. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Since it would be paradoxical if the speaker were referring to this utterance as the one they are paraphrasing, pragmatically the implication is that they are paraphrasing a different, earlier, utterance, and so there is no paradox or recursion.

Comment: I don't think this is really a linguistic question anyway; it's meta-linguistic in nature. @ColinFine's comment is a sufficient answer for this venue - if you want further insight, I suggest asking at [CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Would it better fit at [Philosophy@SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Well did he paraphrase something he had said/written earlier? More context needed.